# Element found in Firebug but not in Selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, firebug

When I check an XPath in Firebug, it works as expected.

The XPath I'm trying is below:

```
.//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.pn`g')][2]
```

[image: Image element found in Firebug]

However, in Selenium WebDriver

```
 ArrayList<WebElement> al = toolActionObject.getAllElementsByXpath(".//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.png')][2]");
 System.out.println(al.size());
```

the output lines are like

```
DEBUG (SeleniumActions.java:91) - Locating elements by By.xpath: *//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.png')][2]
DEBUG (SeleniumActions.java:91) - Locating elements by By.xpath: *//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.png')][2]
DEBUG (SeleniumActions.java:91) - Locating elements by By.xpath: *//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.png')][2]
DEBUG (SeleniumActions.java:91) - Locating elements by By.xpath: *//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.png')][2]
DEBUG (SeleniumActions.java:91) - Locating elements by By.xpath: *//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.png')][2]
DEBUG (SeleniumActions.java:111) - Exception : Elements not found.
 Cause : Elements not found by By.xpath: *//div[Text()='Data Fields']/following::div[contains(@style,'db3a1a10.png')][2]. Returning empty Array List of WebElement.
0
 INFO (GSUILogInLogOut.java:95) - Clossing browser.
PASSED: testHere
```

What is the reason for such conflicting behavior?

Comment: What is `toolActionObject`?

Comment: I am working on a framework. in our framework we have a class called as SeleniumActions in which we defined methods to access Web Elements by id , xpath etc.  toolActionObject is instance of SeleniumActions.

Comment: Please add the relevant html (from where the xpath begins) as text.

Comment: Quite possible that `following::` does not work. Check for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your XPath. `text()` needs to be written lowercase and `'db3a1a10.png'` (probably just an error in your example code) must not contain a tickmark.

Comment: yeah i was trying Text(), it should have been text().